# How to JSON decode array elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JavaScript array that, among others, contains a URL. If I try to simply put the URL in the page (the array is in a project involving the Yahoo! Maps API) it shows the URL as it should be.

But if I try to do a redirect or simply do an 'alert' on the link array element I get:

> function(){return JSON.encode(this);}

As far as I see it this is because the browser does an JSON.encode when it renders the page, thus the link is displayed OK. I have tried several methods to make it redirect (that's what I want to do with the link) correctly (including the usage of 'eval') but with no luck.

After following some suggestions I've run `eval('(' + jsonObject + ')')` but it still returns the same output.

So how's this done ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean... can you post more sample code? The actual array contents and the redirect call would be very helpful.

Answer (score 44):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

[See the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you have an array in PHP as $iniData with 5 fields. If using ajax -

```
echo json_encode($iniData);
```

In Javascript, use the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajaxCalls.php",
            data: "dataType=ini",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                var x = eval('(' + msg + ')');
                $('#allowed').html(x.allowed);              // these are the fields which you can now easily access..
                $('#completed').html(x.completed);
                $('#running').html(x.running);
                $('#expired').html(x.expired);
                $('#balance').html(x.balance);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you get this text in an alert:

```
function(){return JSON.encode(this);}
```

when you try alert(myArray[i]), then there are a few possibilities:

- myArray[i] is a function (most likely)
- myArray[i] is the literal string "function(){return JSON.encode(this);}"
- myArray[i] has a .toString() method that returns that function or that string. This is the least likely of the three.

The simplest way to tell would be to check typeof(myArray[i]).

Comment: I doubt it that is a literal string. Most likely is a function. I have tried to "eval('(' + jsonObject + ')')" but still it returns the same output as before...

Comment: Yeah,  would imagine that passing a function to eval() would call that function's toString method, returning a string that would eval back to that function itself. So that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
eval('(' + jsonObject + ')')
```

Comment: eval is only a safe way to decode JSON data if you 100% trust your source :D

Comment: This cant be eval-ed -> {"code":200,"lang":"en-de","text":["string 1","string 2"]}

Answer (score 1):

JSON decoding in JavaScript is simply an eval() if you trust the string or the more safe code you can find on http://json.org if you don't.

You will then have a JavaScript datastructure that you can traverse for the data you need.

Comment: As I was saying I tried to 'eval' the link element but then it returned 'undefined'. The data in the array comes form parsing a XML, do you think that it can have something to do with that ?

Answer (score 1):

If the object element you get is a function, you can try this:

```
var url = myArray[i]();
```

Answer (score -1):

I decode JSON this way:

```
eval( 'var from_json_object = ' + my_json_str + ';' );
```