# help looping a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, loops

Hi
after a query in php and converting the results to JSON with json_encode i have this:

```
{"ga:visits":"59","ga:pageviews":"117","ga:timeOnSite":"4775.0","average_time_on_site_formatted":"0:01:20","pages_per_visit":"1.98"}
```

my problem is how to loop it and store the keys and values in different variables.

i`m not a javascript guy so please help and give good details.

best regards

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182410/how-to-json-decode-array-elements-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the JSON-string into a Javascript object first. Most browser nowadays have a native support for that in `window.JSON`.

```
var myObj = JSON.parse('{"ga:visits":"59","ga:pageviews":"117","ga:timeOnSite":"4775.0","average_time_on_site_formatted":"0:01:20","pages_per_visit":"1.98"}');
```

After that, you can just loop over the `keys`:

```
for(var key in myObj) {
    console.log(key, ' is: ', myObj[key]);
}
```

If you want to use that in "old'ish" browsers, like IE7 and below you need to use the `json2.js` from http://www.json.org to have the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(str); //str - json string in your example
for(var key in parsedObject){
   // to access each key name - use "key"
   // to acces each value use parsedObject[key]
   document.writeln("key:" + key + "; value: " + parsedObject[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest evaluating it with something like

`var obj = eval(jsonString);`

this will turn the entire string into an object with fields:

- ga:visits
- ga:pageviews
- ga:timeOnSite
- etc.

Then go you can access each variable by name, like `obj.pages_per_visit`

Comment: you would need to have "(" and ")" before and behind the JSON string to make that work.