# Hex numeric entities decoding to use with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, utf-8, emoji

I have a string that contains some emoji codes converted into hex numeric entities, like for example this:

- `&#xd83d;` - �
- `&#xde02;` - �
- `&#xd83d;` - �
- `&#xde02;` - �

What i need is to convert this entities into something readable from javascript when sending from PHP using `json_decode`.

Comment: What is "_something readable from javascript_"?

Comment: After you've written what you need, please share what you did so far and what your programming question is. Stackoverflow is not a Need & Greet site, but about concrete programming quesitons (might sound harder than it is.) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I assume you are asking something similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182410/how-to-json-decode-array-elements-in-javascript

Comment: I actually wonder which emoji those should represent. Can you please reference which ones?

Comment: Ok, guys, i'll try to explain it a bit better. When i display in the browser that numeric entities &#xd83d; &#xde02; it display two squares but it should display a heart (the emoji symbol) so what i need is to convert that codes into another format (unicode i suppose) to display it correctly

Comment: Does this has any sense now?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense because it sounds like you're guessing. Maybe some background information might shed some light: http://www.iamcal.com/emoji-in-web-apps/ - It ships with PHP code btw.

Comment: Just use *decimal* instead of hex.